# How to point Environmental variable SONAR_JAVA_PATH to Java Executable?

Tags: java, sonarqube

After I launched command `StartSonar`, I get this error message:

> ERROR: java.exe not found. Please make sure that the environmental variable SONAR_JAVE_PATH points to the Java executable.

What is Sonar Java Path, and how to point Environmental variable SONAR_JAVA_PATH to Java Executable?

Comment: thanks for reply ,i  have edited my question

Comment: OK, merci! Please do NOT restore the image in your question again. Instead leave the textual-equivalent in it …

Answer (score 0):

Download jdk 11 using the following link: https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html. Open another command prompt after installing jdk 11 and enter "StartSonar" command.